# UITableView crashes on scroll (memory warnings)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have made my first `UITableView`, but when the number of cells is higher than what can be shown on the screen, and I scroll, it then crashes because of lack of memory.

I implemented the `SDWEBIMAGE library` to load the pictures async. and cache the images afterwards.

If more code is needed, please let me know !

I am a complete newbie at this, so please be gentle :)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"defaultcell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];

    }

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 47);
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:spinner];

    //hide labels until done loading
    cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.imageView.hidden = YES;

    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.size={80, 60}}];
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    iv.clipsToBounds = YES;
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(15, 17, 80, 60);

    NSString *profilePicName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self.dbhandler getPicturesPath], [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"filename"]];

    [iv setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePicName]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){
            [spinner stopAnimating];
            cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;
            cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;
            cell.imageView.hidden = NO;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:iv];
        }];

    NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Comments:  %@ \nPosted:        %@", [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"], [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"created_at"]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Votes:    %@",[[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"votes"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

    return cell;
}
```

UPDATED FUNCTION:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"defaultcell";
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
    UIImageView *iv;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
        //build spinner
        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 47);
        spinner.tag = 101;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:spinner];

        //build ImageView
        iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.size={80, 60}}];
        iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        iv.clipsToBounds = YES;
        iv.tag = 102;
        iv.frame = CGRectMake(15, 17, 80, 60);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:iv];
    } else {
        spinner = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        iv = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    }



    [spinner startAnimating];
    //the rest goes here


    cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.imageView.hidden = YES;

    NSString *profilePicName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self.dbhandler getPicturesPath], [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"filename"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", profilePicName);

    [iv setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePicName]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.imageView.hidden = NO;

        NSLog(@"done");
        [cell.contentView addSubview:(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:102]];
    }];


    NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Comments:  %@ \nPosted:        %@", [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"], [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"created_at"]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Votes:    %@",[[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"votes"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It may not fix your problem, but you should add `[spinner removeFromSuperview]` into your completion block.  Also what is the exact exception message you get?

Comment: Right off the bat i just get memory warnings :)

Comment: I tried implementing Mamnus solution, which seems to be the correct way of doing it. Now i just have a problem downloading the image to the imageview iv. Added updated function to question

Answer (score 2):

Every-time you reuse a cell you are adding the UIActivityIndicatorView/spinner and UIImageView/iv as subviews. Better approach is to use a custom Prototype cell in the storyboard or reuse existing views by setting a Tag.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
UIImageView *iv;

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
    //build spinner
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 47);
    spinner.tag = 101;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:spinner];

    //build ImageView
    iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.size={80, 60}}];
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    iv.clipsToBounds = YES;
    iv.tag = 102;
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(15, 17, 80, 60);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:iv];
} else {
    spinner = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    iv = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
}

[spinner startAnimating];
//the rest goes here
```

You need to remove other addSubView calls(specifically in the callback block).

This should help you to get started.

Comment: Wow, this helped me a lot. ty very much. I have one problem now. The original line where i call [iv setImageWithUrl] never finishes, and therefor the complete method doesnt get called. This results in empty cells (because hidden = YES on labels until complete). I think it is because iv is a weak variable and it gets deallocated before it can finish the download? any idea? i added the updated method to my initial question :)

Comment: oh, it seems the object, iv, is null when i call the setImageWithUrl method. any ideas?

Comment: same with spinner. its also null

Comment: Sorry since the spinner and imageView are added in cell.contentView, we have to call viewWithTag on contentView. See the updated else block.

Comment: I actually tried that earlier, and again just now, and i still get null in return.

Comment: I inserted this after the if else statement: NSLog(@"iv: %@", iv);
    NSLog(@"spinner: %@", spinner);

Comment: I tried placing an nslog in the if part of the statement, and it never gets logged. it seems it never even go into the if, only the else part

Comment: i figured out why now.. Its because cell is never nil. Now i do the check on [cell.contentView viewWithTag: 102] instead

Comment: my only problem is that the image doesnt get updated now, until i select the cell...